# Getting a list of WiFi networks nearby when the adapter is in AP mode

Tags: networking, command-line, configuration, wifi

I am trying to get a list of wireless networks nearby while the adapter is acting as an access point but iwlist returns the following error:

```
$ sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning : Operation not supported
```

Is there another way of getting this list, perhaps with another utility? My Tomato powered WRT54 seems to be able to achieve this (listing nearby APs while the device itself is set up as an AP), so I'm curious how I could replicate that behaviour.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`iwlist` is seriously deprecated. Remove it from your system and never use it again. Do the same with `iwconfig`, `iwspy`. Those tools are ancient and were designed in an era where 802.11n didn't exist. Kernel developers maintain a ugly compatibility layer to still support `wireless-tools`, and this compatibility layer often lies.

---

Now install `iw` if not already done. The `iw` command you are looking for is

`iw dev wlan0 scan ap-force`.

This is a fairly recent addition. Not all drivers support this, but most should do.

Comment: Thanks, I was completely unaware that `iwlist` was deprecated! I had to compile `iw` from source, as the version I had in my distro was too old, but after that I was able to retrieve the AP list.

Comment: @BatchyX - There is no package called `iw`, at least not on Debian Wheezy. Where can I get this `iw` ?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue when my wifi device was in 'Access Point' Mode. I changed mode to 'client'. Then command started working perfectly. Command works with 'ad-hoc' mode as well.